# How can I switch between the Repository Registry and the active repository tabs

Tags: mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

In TortoiseHg Workbench what is the keyboard shortcut to switch between the Repository Registry and the active repository tabs?

Normally I would expect <kbd>F6</kbd> to do this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Just filed issue [Keyboard shortcut (hotkey) to switch between Repository Registry and the active repository tab](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/5285/keyboard-shortcut-hotkey-to-switch-between)

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/workbench.html?highlight=keyboard#keyboard-navigation) is all the keyboard navigation mentioned in TortoiseHg's manual. Not very helpful. However, it also refers to the [list of key sequences](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/KeySequences) in the TortoiseHg wiki. I still don't see a shortcut for what you want, but take a look maybe.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't seem to be in the manual or wiki. It's a shame as it's not possible navigate keyboard only without it.